# Investment analysis software

Tags: project-management, time-management, finance, accounting

I'm looking for software for investment analysis. It should be able to calculate and visualize:

- NPV

  - Net present value of an investment after 3, 5, 10 years
- IRR

  - Internal rate of return
- ROI

  - Return on investment: profit compared to bank interest
- BEP

  - Break-even point: when invested capital is returned

Is there any software to calculate and visualize these conveniently by getting intuitive inputs?

The platform or operating system doesn't matter. Technology doesn't matter.

##### Update

To specify what kind of financial products I'm more interested in for analysis:

- An existing portfolio? No.
- Analyzing products? Kind of.
- Startup investment? Yes.

Comment: Does this calculate NPV, ROI, BEP? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GnuCash

Comment: Would a spreadsheet be acceptable?

Comment: @EricS It would be fine if it has the visualizations and charts =)

Comment: Please also specify what kind of financial products you are more interested in for analysis. Is it for an existing portfolio? Or just for analysing products?

Answer (score 0):

This [Excel template](https://www.someka.net/excel-template/npv-irr-calculator/) might be helpful.

Also, there is [this spreadsheet template](https://www.vertex42.com/Calculators/npv-irr-calculator.html).